# how to make php header execute after some second when the html file load completely

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

i have problem when i'm trying to read page and convert it to doc file

everything is fine but because i'm using angularJs in the page it read the command of angular inside my doc file

```
$contents = View::make('EmployeeDownloadCv');


$headers = array(
    "Content-type"=>"text/html",
    "Content-Disposition"=>"attachment;Filename=myfile.doc"
);



return Response::make($contents,200, $headers);
```

what i mean is the file doesn't read the data which came from angular because angular need at least 2 second to load the data but header php read the file before this 2 second

any idea please

my result now contain @{{user}} but i expect to get instead of  @{{user}} the real name if user which came from angular function

> i'm working with laravel now but the problem is same on pure php

any suggest please

Comment: You can't send any headers after you've already sent the content to the client. Headers must be sent first, then the content. When all your PHP has been executed on the server, it will send the result to the browser, that will trigger any JS.

Comment: You should try AJAX...

Comment: I've never seen anyone do a force download through Ajax, though.

Answer (score 0):

*you could try for a while ... to sleep before your header ...*
*http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php*
*sleep(3);*

Seem that i had not well understand the question, so maybe 
this will help and is what you're searching for:
http://php.net/manual/it/function.ob-get-contents.php

Comment: How will that send the HTML to the client and wait before executing the PHP?

Comment: well you can only imagine what functions are doing so ...maybe  `$contents = View::make('EmployeeDownloadCv');
sleep(3);
$headers = array(
    "Content-type"=>"text/html",
    "Content-Disposition"=>"attachment;Filename=myfile.doc"
);
return Response::make($contents,200, $headers);`

Comment: You do know that headers must be sent first, before content? And that `sleep()` will only "pause" the php execution, including sending the content to the server as well? So putting `sleep()` first will only delay the same result as before. The first `View`-call doesn't actually execute any JS, it only returns the markup to that variable. Nothing has been sent to the browser at that point.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I agree to your point and hence I find axew3's answer confusing.

Comment: think you have to put what the functions called are doing so:  $contents = View::make('EmployeeDownloadCv'); do not create the document?

Comment: No, That function just returns the view content to the variable, as a string. PHP don't care about the content. It's the browser that parses any HTML and JS _after_ it's been sent to the browser. Which happens _after_ any headers are sent. So, this answer is totally wrong and won't do what the OP asks.

Comment: well as you functions aren't doing what are named for ... perhaps this will help http://php.net/manual/it/function.ob-get-contents.php

Comment: The OP is using Laravel's functions, and they do what they say. You don't seem to understand the issue. Headers must _always_ be sent before _any_ html or js is sent to the browser. So the headers will _always_ be sent before the javascript will be executed.

Comment: so, to resume, you think nor http://php.net/manual/it/function.ob-get-contents.php will not resolve your problem? Have you take a look?